# user pointer in python

Tags: python, ctypes, v4l2

*I am trying to display preview from webcam captured using v4l.

Here is an idea of how the code looks like:

```
from ctypes import *
from v4l2 import *
from Image import fromstring
from Tkinter import Tk, Label
from ImageTk import PhotoImage
from ctypes.util import find_library

libc = CDLL(find_library('c'))
posix_memalign = libc.posix_memalign
getpagesize = libc.getpagesize


device_name = '/dev/video0'
ps = preview_settings = {
    'width': 320,
    'height': 240,
    'pixformat': 'RGB',
    }
PIX_FMT = V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB555


preview = Tk()
image = PhotoImage(ps['pixformat'], (ps['width'], ps['height']))
label = Label(preview, text='Preview', image=image, width=ps['width'], height=ps['height'])
label.pack()


capability = v4l2_capability()
size = v4l2_frmsizeenum()
format = v4l2_format()
request = v4l2_requestbuffers()
buffer = v4l2_buffer()
b_address = c_void_p()
frame_name_count = '0'
type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE

device = open(device_name, 'rw')

ioctl(device, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, addr(capability))

size.pixel_format = PIX_FMT 
size.index = 0

format.type = type
format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = PIX_FMT
format.fmt.pix.width = size.discrete.width
format.fmt.pix.height = size.discrete.height
format.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE
format.fmt.pix.bytesperline = 0
format.fmt.pix.sizeimage = 0

request.type = type
request.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR
request.count = 1

ioctl(device, VIDIOC_S_FMT, addr(format))

ioctl(device, VIDIOC_G_FMT, addr(format))

ioctl(device, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, addr(request))

posix_memalign(addressof(b_address), getpagesize(), format.fmt.pix.sizeimage)

buffer.type = request.type
buffer.memory = request.memory
buffer.index = 0
buffer.m.userptr = b_address.value
buffer.length = format.fmt.pix.sizeimage

while True:

    ioctl(device, VIDIOC_QBUF, addr(buffer))

    ioctl(device, VIDIOC_STREAMON, cast(type, c_void_p))

    ioctl(device, VIDIOC_DQBUF, addr(buffer))

    preview_data = string_at(buffer.m.userptr, buffer.length)
    im = fromstring(ps['pixformat'], (ps['width'], ps['height']), preview_data)
    image.paste(im)
    preview.update()
```

*and I get* `ValueError: not enough image data`

---

*well, I import*

```
c_lib = CDLL(find_library('c'))
posix_memalign = c_lib.posix_memalign
getpagesize = c_lib.getpagesize
```

*and then after*

```
ioctl(device, VIDIOC_S_FMT, addr(format))
ioctl(device, VIDIOC_G_FMT, addr(format))
```

*and stuff like that, I try to acquire memory*

```
posix_memalign(addressof(b_address), getpagesize(), format.fmt.pix.sizeimage)
```

*now b_address is no longer = None*
*b_address is something like* `c_void_p(145014784)`

*then I start the loop, QBUF, DQBUF, etc..*

*the thing is, that when I call pygame.image.frombuffer*

```
pg_img = pygame.image.frombuffer(
         buffer.m.userptr,
         (format.fmt.pix.width, format.fmt.pix.height),
         preview_settings['pixformat']
         )
```

*I get* **TypeError: expected a character buffer object**

Answer (score 1):

Looks like [`ctypes.string_at(address, size)`](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.string_at) is what you want. That'll give you a python string buffer with the contents of the memory at your pointer's address. This should be suitable to pass to `Image.fromstring` or `pygame.image.frombuffer`.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you very much. That really helped.

I now get ValueError, though:

    ValueError: not enough image data

and I will have to investigate further on that

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about ctypes, but I am doing a similar thing (wrapped c++ webcam capture, displayed with DirectPython).

In my case I just made a buffer in python like this:

```
bufferSize = imageWidth * imageHeight
buf = "\0" * bufferSize
```

Pass buf to your image capture function for filling?

Maybe post a more complete code sample...

Comment: I am trying to use nothing else but python and bindings for python to capture and display frames from camera using v4l.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing `buffer` directly as the first arg?  If that doesn't work and you want to make a writeable character buffer with `ctypes`, [create_string_buffer](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=buffer#ctypes.create_string_buffer) is the only way I know (I don't understand where you're getting the `b_address.value` *from*).

Comment: b_address is assigned when posix_memalign is called.

I am not sure that addresof(b_address) is the correct way to pass that argument and therefore not sure if that's not the actual problem. not the frombuffer method

Answer (score 0):

*OK, what I did was to leave pygame for Tkinter and PIL*

*now after the same allocation I pass* `buffer.m.userptr` *to fromstring method from Image

*first I have, of course, the following:*

```
import Image
import Tkinter

tk = Tkinter.Tk()
preview = ImageTk.PhotoImage(ps['pixformat'], (ps['width'], ps['height']))
label = Tkinter.Label(tk, text='Preview', image=preview, width=ps['width'], height=ps['height'])
label.pack()
```

*and now preview:*

```
im = Image.fromstring(ps['pixformat'], (format.fmt.pix.width, format.fmt.pix.height), '\0'*buffer.m.userptr)
preview.paste(im)
tk.update()
```

*I did what @sipickles said, with '\0' to see if the whole thing will work*
*And it did :)*

*the thing is how to pas that userptr correctly and is the data in it actually what it needs to be passed to the preview*

*I am really lost here. Someone knows v4l2?*

Answer (score 0):

*Ok. so for now I fixed the sizeimage problem by setting the sizeimage myself:*

*Now frombuffer displays something that is not the frame from the buffer.*

```
from ctypes import *
from v4l2 import *
from Image import fromstring
from Tkinter import Tk, Label
from ImageTk import PhotoImage
from ctypes.util import find_library

libc = CDLL(find_library('c'))
posix_memalign = libc.posix_memalign
getpagesize = libc.getpagesize


device_name = '/dev/video0'
ps = preview_settings = {
    'width': 320,
    'height': 240,
    'pixformat': 'RGB',
    }
PIX_FMT = V4L2_PIX_FMT_RGB555


preview = Tk()
image = PhotoImage(ps['pixformat'], (ps['width'], ps['height']))
label = Label(preview, text='Preview', image=image, width=ps['width'], height=ps['height'])
label.pack()


capability = v4l2_capability()
size = v4l2_frmsizeenum()
format = v4l2_format()
request = v4l2_requestbuffers()
buffer = v4l2_buffer()
b_address = c_void_p()
type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE

device = open(device_name, 'rw')

ioctl(device, VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, capability)

size.pixel_format = PIX_FMT 
size.index = 0

format.type = type
format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = PIX_FMT
format.fmt.pix.width = size.discrete.width
format.fmt.pix.height = size.discrete.height
format.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE

request.type = type
request.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR
request.count = 1

format.fmt.pix.sizeimage = format.fmt.pix.width * format.fmt.pix.height * 4
buffer.length = format.fmt.pix.sizeimage

ioctl(device, VIDIOC_S_FMT, format)

posix_memalign(byref(b_address), getpagesize(), format.fmt.pix.sizeimage)

buffer.m.userptr = b_address.value

buffer.type = request.type
buffer.memory = request.memory

ioctl(device, VIDIOC_REQBUFS, request)

while True:

    ioctl(device, VIDIOC_QBUF, buffer)

    ioctl(device, VIDIOC_STREAMON, cast(type, c_void_p))

    ioctl(device, VIDIOC_DQBUF, buffer)

    **# What happens here? preview_data is wrong?**
    preview_data = string_at(buffer.m.userptr, buffer.length)

    im = frombuffer(ps['pixformat'], (ps['width'], ps['height']), preview_data)
    image.paste(im)
    preview.update()
```