# VIDIOC_QBUF: Invalid argument V4l2 MEMORY USERPTR python implementation

Tags: python, buffer, linux-device-driver, ioctl, v4l2

I am trying to work with user-pointer v4l2 driver.
Currently I am working with the v4l2 MMAP and its working fine, but I want to change it to user pointer because of reading performance.

Working example (with mmap):

```
def init_mmap(self, width=8192, height=256):
    req = v4l2_requestbuffers()
    req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP  # V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR
    req.count = 1  # number of buffer frames

    self.height = max(self.height, 32)

    # get device capabilities
    cp = v4l2_capability()
    fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, cp)

    # Configure v4l2 format
    fmt = v4l2_format()
    fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    fmt.fmt.pix.width = self.width  # 8192
    fmt.fmt.pix.height = self.height  # 256
    fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_RG12
    fmt.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE
    fmt.fmt.pix.bytesperline = 0

    fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_S_FMT, fmt)

    # init mmap capture
    fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_REQBUFS, req)  # tell the driver that we want some buffers

    for ind in range(self.req.count):
        print(f"allocate MMAP buffer {ind}")
        buf = v4l2_buffer()
        buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
        buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP
        buf.index = ind
        buf.reserved = 0
        buf.flags = 0
      
        # queue the buffer for capture
        ret = fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QBUF, buf)  # return 0 on success.
        if ret != 0:
            print("Could not allocate buffers!")
            return -1

    fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, buf)

    return 0
```

What I am trying to achieve (userptr):

```
def init_userptr(self, width=8192, height=256, buffer=None):
    req = v4l2_requestbuffers()
    req.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    req.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR  # V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR
    req.count = 1  # number of buffer frames

    self.height = max(self.height, 32)

    # get device capabilities
    cp = v4l2_capability()
    fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QUERYCAP, cp)

    # Configure v4l2 format
    fmt = v4l2_format()
    fmt.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    fmt.fmt.pix.width = self.width  # 8192
    fmt.fmt.pix.height = self.height  # 256
    fmt.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_RG12
    fmt.fmt.pix.field = V4L2_FIELD_NONE
    fmt.fmt.pix.bytesperline = 0

    fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_S_FMT, fmt)

    # init mmap capture
    fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_REQBUFS, req)  # tell the driver that we want some buffers

    for ind in range(self.req.count):
        print(f"allocate USERPTR buffer {ind}")
        buf = v4l2_buffer()
        buf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
        buf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR
        buf.index = ind
        buf.m.userptr = ctypes.c_ulong(ctypes.addressof(buffer[ind]))  # Tried id(buffer) as well and few more similar options
        buf.length = len(buffer)  # ctypes.c_uint32(len(buffer)) 

        # queue the buffer for capture
        ret = fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QBUF, buf)  # ## FAILS HERE ## #
        if ret != 0:
            print("Could not allocate buffers!")
            return -1

    fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QUERYBUF, buf)

    return 0
```

The buffer in the section above was allocated as so:

```
arr = ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.ARRAY(ctypes.c_float, 4194304), 3)
buffer = arr()
```

The code fails at the line `ret = fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QBUF, buf)` with the error:
**"OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument"**

After doing some reading I came across this:
"**The buffer type is not supported, or the index is out of bounds, or no buffers have been allocated yet, or the userptr or length are invalid.**"

Which was not so helpful.

I have found some C implementations of user-pointer v4l2 readings, but I could not make it work on my python code.

I have tried to allocate buffers with ctypes, and bytearray, but got the same result every time.

**Relevant info:**

C Implementation -
https://gist.github.com/maxlapshin/1253534

videodev2.h -
https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/videodev2.h#L1114

ioctl VIDIOC_QBUF, VIDIOC_DQBUF - https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.15/media/uapi/v4l/vidioc-qbuf.html

**EDIT:**

Ok so after some more reading I managed to make
`ret = fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QBUF, buf)` to work by changing the way I am allocating the buffers.

The buffer allocation:

```
    b_address = ctypes.c_void_p()
    buf.length = fmt.fmt.pix.width * fmt.fmt.pix.height * 2
    posix_memalign(ctypes.byref(b_address), getpagesize(), buf.length)
    buf.m.userptr = b_address.value
    buf.type = self.req.type
    buf.memory = self.req.memory
    ret = fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_QBUF, buf) # this line is now working!
```

I used this post as reference - [user pointer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2070768/user-pointer-in-python)

Now I am facing a new issue with `select()`. It reaches time out and then hangs on **VIDIOC_DQBUF** when I try to read frame.

Example:

```
def get_frame(self):  
    dbuf = v4l2_buffer()
    dbuf.type = V4L2_BUF_TYPE_VIDEO_CAPTURE
    dbuf.memory = V4L2_MEMORY_USERPTR  # V4L2_MEMORY_MMAP

    # wait till buffer is ready for reading
    t0 = time.time()
    max_t = 5
    ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = ([], [], [])
    while len(ready_to_read) == 0 and time.time() - t0 < max_t:
        ready_to_read, ready_to_write, in_error = select.select([self.vid.fileno()], [], [], max_t)  # Reaches time out here
    # read (de-queue) buffer
    ret = fcntl.ioctl(self.vid.fileno(), VIDIOC_DQBUF, dbuf)  # Hangs here.
```

I understand that this issue is related to buffers size or maybe incorrect allocations, but really I cant point my finger on a specific thing.

Any help will be much appreciated!

**Thank you all in advance!**

Comment: maybe you allocated buffers that are too short or too long, why do you set it to float?

Comment: Thank you for the respond, I have tried to set it to byte array as well and got the same result. In regards to buffers size, I changed it number of time with no success..

Comment: what driver is that, you can check with `v4l2-ctl -d<n> --all`

Comment: Driver Info:
        Driver name   : tegra-video
        Card type     : vi-output, imx185 2-0036
        Bus info      : platform:15700000.vi:2
        Driver version: 4.9.140